# Is it possible to find out which user dropped a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, logging, drop

Is there a transaction log or any other way to find out which user (and when) dropped some table from the database? I am working with Postgres DB.
Thanks.

Comment: Short answer, out of the box no.  Longer answer, if you have the Postgres [logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) cranked up you could possibly figure it out from there. You could also use [Event Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html).